# Using a Singleton to fix BottomNavigationActivity removing Fragment on navigation

Tags: android, fragment

BottomNavigationActivity as well as NavigationDrawerActivity removefragments on navigation and don't add them to the Back Stack. Therefore one has to rebuild the view from scratch on each fragment navigation change. I have a fragment that is painfull to rebuild so I found fix that consist in storing the Fragment View inside a Singleton when onCreateView is called for the first time and then on subsequent call onCreateView just return the View saved in the Singleton (after removing itself from its parent) instead of inflate a knew View.

So my question is there a problem with this approach ? Any better fix ?

TIA